# Is it possible to omit "for people" in a sentence?

Tags: ellipsis

I have a question regarding the sentence below.

> This book is intended to make it easier to be informed.

I interpreted this sentence as

> This book is intended to make it easier for people to be informed.

Is it possible to omit "for people" in this way? Or, is my understanding not correct?

Comment: You understood the sentence correctly. It could also be understood to mean 'for the reader to be informed' (that is, anyone who reads the book).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can omit it. If you do so you allow the reader to work out for whom the book is intended, from context.

In this case, without "for people" I'd assume it was for the *readers of the book* to become better informed, and not all people.  I prefer the sentence without "for people" - it seems odd to say that book is for all people (and not only those people who read the book)